# Inner join and left join with query inside - from SQL to LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, join

I have prepared a SQL query and I'm having problem translating into LINQ query. Below I'm attaching my SQL query.

I have problems with `inner join` and `left join` that contains a `select` inside, and actually a second `left join` has another `select` inside a `select` as well, with `group by`. 
This is really frustrating so maybe you could help me?

```
select * from Users u
inner join Pickups p on p.Number=u.Number
inner join Revisions r on r.Id=p.RevisionId and r.RevisionText='Done'
inner join (select u2.Id, count(u2.Id) clicks_num 
            from Users u2
            inner join Clicks uc on uc.UserId=u2.Id
            group by u2.Id) clicks on clicks.Id=u.Id
left join (select UserId, count(Id) scc 
           from (select distinct ucx.UserId, ucx.Id 
                from Clicks ucx
                inner join Pickups ucpx on ucpx.Number=ucx.Number
                inner join Revisions ucprx on ucprx.Id=ucpx.RevisionId and r.RevisionText='Done') t
                group by UserId) s on s.UserId = u.Id
where clicks.clicks_num = s.scc;
```

I am starting with a simple one, but then could you give me an example how to make an inner select as join?

```
from u in Context.Set<Users>()
join p in Context.Set<Pickups>() on u.Number equals p.Number
join r in Context.Set<Revisions>() on p.RevisionId equals r.RevisionId
```

Comment: Since you reference `c` in the `where` clause, you have effectively transformed the `left join` into an `inner join`.  That should make it easier to translate.

Comment: Have you tried https://www.sqltolinq.com/? I can't run it for you as it needs connection to the database but seems promising and has 20 days trial.

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras I am using .NET Core and EF Core, so this tool is not usable for me.

Comment: how about putting this query in a sql stored procedure and calling your sp when you need to.